# Issue in getting previsouly created HttpSession with Atmosphere request

Tags: spring, atmosphere

I am using atmosphere for server side push and enabled the http session support as well.  Problem I am facing is I am not able to get the HttpSession object which was created in earlier requests.

Example :

Step 1 : making login request...... HttpSession got created

Step 2 : making another request for some resource .... same session is present

Step 3 : making Atomoshpere request

/xyz/pqr?X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-atmo-protocol=true&X-Atmosphere-   tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.1&X-Cache-Date=0

Now at the server side when I say

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
logger.debug("session Id:"+((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getId());
}
```

This time what I am seeing is the session id is new one and not of the previously created HttpSession object.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here.

Thanks,
Bond

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to send the cookie in header with JSESSIONID. It was going as 'set-cookie' instead of 'cookie'

Thanks,
Bond